Implication of declaring a class with without sharing keyword and providing its access to guest user
I have created a class with without sharing keyword and I have provided access of this class to guest user profile. This class is being called from a LWC component which is hosted on public support site in salesforce. Inside that class I am accessing a Metadata field to get key. Later I am calling some rest endpoint using this key.
public without sharing class MyRestCalloutClass {

// Declare a static string variable at the class level

  private static List<My_Metadata_Type__mdt> metadataRecord = [Select key from My_Metadata_Type__mdt limit 1];
    private static String bearerToken = metadataRecord.size()>0 ? metadataRecord[0].key : null;

// Method to perform REST callout

public static void makeRestCallout() {
    String endpoint = 'https://api.example.com/endpoint';

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + bearerToken);

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    // Handle response here
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        // Successful response handling
        System.debug('REST callout successful');
        MyCustomObject__c ccTemp = new MyCustomObject__c();
        ccTemp.result = ''+response.getBody();
        insert ccTemp;

    } else {
        // Error handling
        System.debug('REST callout failed with status code: ' + response.getStatusCode());
    }
}}

My query is:
Is there any security implication in using above approach?

Sharing does not apply to custom metadata type records, but then you do not need to use SOQL to get the record in your code - use one of the get methods instead (unless you have a long text area field you need the whole value of). That said, guest user and sharing/security is a whole topic in themselves. To be clear - if this is all the class does, this is not a security concern.

You do have a potential CRUD/FLS issue in that you assume you can always insert a new record of your custom object without permission checks, but that is nothing to do with sharing.
